# Zsh / git: Tab autocomplete not working if "HEAD^" is next to last word on input row

Tags: git, zsh, autocomplete

## Problem

I have the following

```
git reset HEAD^ half_entered_file_n<Tab>
```

At this point I would like the half_entered_file_name.txt to be Tab-completed.

## My own investigation

I can get Tab completion to work if i write

```
git reset HEAD\^ ...
```

instead, escaping the "^".

Writing a "^" as the last character doesn't seem to affect autocomplete, unless HEAD is also present:

```
#autocomplete works
git reset RANDOM^ half_entered_file_n<Tab> #works
```

## Zsh configuration

I am using Oh-my-zsh. On top of oh-my-zsh, i have configured the following which may be relevant:

```
# Let <TAB> auto completion add a slash at the end instead of space (like BASH)
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true 

# Unless this option is set, you can't write git checkout HEAD^^ without escaping ^ as \^ in zsh
setopt NO_NOMATCH 

# Standard git plugins
plugins=(git git-extras)
```

For completeness, [here is my configuration](https://github.com/bes/Besettings/blob/master/MacOSX/dot.zshrc)

I am running this on OSX in iTerm2.

Thanks!

## Update

I have found some semi-solutions, but none that lead to an "answered" status yet, which basically makes them non-solutions.

1. set `compdef -d git` in .zshrc [as proposed by "caveman"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810327/git-tab-autocompletion-is-useless-can-i-turn-it-off-or-optimize-it)

   - Solves: Now HEAD^ no longer breaks file autocompletion.
   - Drawback: git command autocompletion doesn't work anymore.
2. Use the [accepted answer by "ralphtheninja" from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810327/git-tab-autocompletion-is-useless-can-i-turn-it-off-or-optimize-it)

   - Solves: Should replace the way the file completion list is generated, which would solve the problem.
   - Drawback: Doesn't work. It seems git-completion.zsh/.bash has changed syntax.

I don't know shell scripting well enough to understand exactly what is going on in git-completion.zsh/.bash, and if that is the reason things are breaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why you shouldn't assume

For the longest time I was assuming that the git completion in my zsh configuration was coming from `/usr/local/share/git-core/contrib/completion/`, specifically from `git-completion.zsh` or even `git-completion.bash`. I guess I was assuming this because most searches will yield results talking about these files. However I didn't explicitly include any of these files and for the longest time I was just guessing oh-my-zsh was including them.

But...

## We're not in Kansas anymore

It wasn't until I used zsh method tracing, enabled via `setopt xtrace`, that I realized (by googling some method names) that the script being used was in fact `/usr/local/share/zsh/functions/_git`. I had previously used [XCode Instruments.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/how-to-monitor-file-access-for-an-os-x-application) to monitor which scripts were being accessed on the file system, but didn't figure it out then (the output is quite chatty, and shows accesses from other apps as well).

## What's going on?

The traces showed this (partial traces ahead!)

```
git reset HEAD <TAB>
...
+__git_tree_files:17> tree=HEAD
+__git_tree_files:18> tree_files+=+__git_tree_files:18> _call_program tree-files git ls-tree --name-only -z HEAD ./
+__git_tree_files:18> tree_files+=( first second third )
```

And

```
git reset HEAD^ <TAB>
...
+__git_tree_files:17> tree=HEAD^
+__git_tree_files:18> tree_files+=+__git_tree_files:18> _call_program tree-files git ls-tree --name-only -z 'HEAD^' ./
+__git_tree_files:18> tree_files+=( )
```

That empty `tree_files` looks suspicious.

On line 6058 in `/usr/local/share/zsh/functions/_git` we find

```
tree_files+=(${(ps:\0:)"$(_call_program tree-files git ls-tree $extra_args --name-only -z $tree $Path 2>/dev/null)"})
```

We definitely need to escape that `$tree` variable. Said and done:

```
tree_files+=(${(ps:\0:)"$(_call_program tree-files git ls-tree $extra_args --name-only -z ${(q)tree} $Path 2>/dev/null)"})
```

## Epilogue

There are some more bugs going on in this script (e.g. the file list for `git reset <tree-ish>` is based on the `<tree-ish>`, when it should be based on HEAD. Now I know where to fix them!

## Update

There is also the possibility of running the completion scripts from git instead. [You can do that by following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028740/git-tab-completion-in-zsh-throwing-errors).

Comment: May I suggest a bug report to http://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/bugs/ so it can be fixed upstream?